# Що таке "ампля"?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів

Шукаючи визначення ***ампельні рослини*** наткнулась на дивне, для мене, слово ***ампля***.

> ***[Ампельні рослини](http://www.jnsm.com.ua/cgi-bin/u/book/sis.pl?Article=1225&action=show)*** - декоративні рослини із звисаючими
>   пагонами, стеблами або листками, які вирощують у підвісних вазах
>   (**амплях**) або горщиках.

У [Словник лемківскої говірки](https://ukrainian_lemko.academic.ru/160) знайшла таке тлумачення:

> ***Ампля*** -лі, ж. - Лампа, що вісить, закрита знизу.

**Чи є правильним використовувати слова "ампля" для назви виду горщика?**

Answer (score 2):

Натрапила на це слово у [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/44/53392/295881.html):

> **АМПЕЛЬ** 
>   (нім.) 
>   Підвісна ваза в інтер'єрі.

Отже, М.в. мнж. **ампель** -**амплях**. Це слово має те ж тлумаченя, що подане в наведеному реченні перед душками - "*які вирощують у підвісних вазах (**амплях**)"*.